# Where could exit button be removed from during onboarding process?

Tags: usability, mobile-application, subscription

My company is re-designing the on-boarding process for Emergency Service within the app. The process as follows:

> Page 1: Intro of Emergency Service
>
> Page 2: Terms of Services (TOS)
>
> Page 3: Permission Needed from user
>
> Page 4-9: Collection of personal/medical data from users for emergency
>   service in the case of emergency situation

There's an exit button from page 1-3 but not on page 4-9 onwards. However, "Back" button is presented from page 4-9.

My rational to remove exit button from Page 4- 9 as follows:

1. Users have 3 opportunities to exit the process in the beginning
2. Checked other 20 apps and found that all of them have no exit button after you agree on TOS and then start asking for your detailed information

Could anyone chip in or validate the user experience on lack of exit button after Page 3?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the exit option takes away the freedom for users to leave, forcing them to either complete the form or risk losing input data.

Users might want to leave your application for a moment to return later.
I would keep the exit button and provide the option to 'Save draft'.